# Highmaps touch option for selecting multiple

Tags: select, touch, multi-touch, shift, highmaps

Is there a way to use touch gestures to select/deselect more than one point in `Highcharts`?  This works great in non-touch use cases using the `Shift + click` to select.  Ideally we could specify two tap or double tap, etc for this functionality.

Here is the `Highchart` demo that I am working off of.

```
[JS Fiddle][1]
```